# Type of pointer to member from base class

Tags: c++, member-pointers

I have a problem regarding member pointers. The following code fails to compile using both Oracle Solaris Studio 12.2's CC and cygwin GCC 4.3.4 but works with Microsoft Visual C++ 2010:

```
struct A {
  int x;
};

struct B : public A {
};

template<typename T> class Bar {
public:
  template<typename M> void foo(M T::*p);
};

int main(int, char *[]) {
    Bar<B> bbar;
    bbar.foo(&B::x);
    return 0;
}
```

At the next to last line both compilers mentioned above fail to find a match for `Bar<B>::foo(int A::*)`. I wrote a simple test to confirm that the type of the expression `&B::x` is actually `int A::*`:

```
// ...

static void foo(int A::*p) {
  std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
}

static void foo(int B::*p) {
  std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
}

int main(int, char *[]) {
    foo(&B::x);  // prints "A", even on MS VC++ 2010 
    return 0;
}
```

The following workaround works with GCC (not tested with Oracle CC yet) but fails with VC++ due to ambiguity:

```
template<typename T> class Bar {
public:
  template<typename M> void foo(M T::*p);
  template<typename M, typename _T_base> inline void foo(M _T_base::*p) {
      foo(static_cast<M T::*>(p));
  }
};
```

*My question:
Which behavior is correct? Apparently VC++ does an implicit upcast from `int A::*` to `int B::*` to satisfy the call to the member function template, shouldn't the other two compilers consider doing the same?*

Comment: Interested in the answer too, as have met similar problem myself. My understanding is that the expectation of `&B::x` being silently cast to `&A::x` is wrong due to multiple inheritance: instance of `B` might contain several instances of `A`, thus `&B::x` is (potentially) ambiguous.

Comment: From my deleted answer: `static_cast< int B::* >( &B::x )` also works.

Comment: @Dummy00001: I suspect that in presence of multiple inheritance, the compiler would behave like all other base-class member resolutions and output an error stating the name is ambiguous. If the compiler is able to resolve the name (it should, here) then it should resolve it without a fuss.

Comment: @Andre: The problem is that there is no entity `B::x`. If we break it down, there is the qualifier `B::`, which gets us into B's scope, and then `x`, which looks up an object *starting* with B's scope. We find an object `x`, and indeed if we found two `x` there would be an error, but `x` is still associated with `A` not `B`, because the scope it is found in is `A` 's.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A conversion from `int A::*` to `int B::*` is allowed, and that's not the problem.  The problem is in template argument deduction, as you can see if you try the following program which supplies a template argument `<int>` for `B::foo` and compiles, and a non-member function `foo2` which produces the same error as `B::foo` did before.

```
struct A {
  int x;
};

struct B : public A {
};

template <typename T> class Bar {
public:
  template<typename M> void foo(M T::*p);
};

template<typename M> void foo2(M B::*p);

int main(int, char*[]) {
  Bar<B> bbar;
  bbar.foo<int>(&B::x);
  foo2(&B::x); // error, but foo2<int>(&B::x) would work.
  return 0;
}
```

I think this situation is not covered by the cases where the compiler is supposed to deduce the template argument `<int>` on its own.  14.8.2.1p3:

> In general, the deduction process attempts to find template argument values that will make the deduced A identical to A (after the type A is transformed as described above). However, there are three cases that allow a difference:

- If the original P is a reference type, the deduced A (i.e., the type referred to by the reference) can be more cv-qualified than A.
- A can be another pointer or pointer to member type that can be converted to the deduced A via a qualification conversion (conv.qual).
- If P is a class, and P has the form template-id, then A can be a derived class of the deduced A. Likewise, if P is a pointer to a class of the form template-id, A can be a pointer to a derived class pointed to by the deduced A.

Here "P" is the template function's argument type: `M B::*p`, where template type parameter `M` is to be determined.  "A" is the type of the actual argument: `int A::*`.  P and A are certainly not a reference or a class, and the sort of pointer-to-member conversion we would need for this to work is not a qualification conversion (which describes only const/volatile manipulations like `X*` to `const X*` or `int X::*` to `const int X::*`).

So the template argument cannot be deduced, and you should add the `<int>` explicit template parameter to your code.

Comment: Deduction can't happen anyway when you also need to convert. Between this and Dummy's comment, I think this is pretty well answered. +1

Comment: Actually, template parameter deduction and argument conversion is allowed in a few situations.  For example, `template <typename T> void f(const T*); void g(int* ptr) { f(ptr); }` is legal, and the compiler must deduce `T` is `int` and convert `ptr` to `const int*`.