# type of pointer to base's data member due to standard

Tags: c++, standards, pointer-to-member

type of `&Derived::member` expression from following snippet is not `int Derived:: *`, but `int Base:: *` (with g++5) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct Base { int member ; } ;
struct Derived : Base {} ;

int main ( )
{   
    std::cerr << typeid( &Derived::member ).name() ;       
    return 0 ;
}
```

*according to standard, is it expected behavior.?* 
can't find nothing, that can clarify this example.

there are at least [t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859517/type-of-pointer-to-member-from-base-class)w[o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519855/address-of-c-pointer-to-class-data-member-in-visual-studio) similar questions, but none of them has needed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

g++ is right.

From the C++11 Standard:

> **5.3.1 Unary operators**
>
> 3 The result of the unary & operator is a pointer to its operand.
>
> ...
>
> ```
>  struct A { int i; };
>  struct B : A { };
>  ... &B::i ... // has type int A::*
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing that is the scope of of int member is within Base and not Derived.

With inheritance, the int member can be accessed, but it is still in Base's scope.